# Como detectar la creación de un nuevo archivo en un directorio de Google Drive?

Tags: php, google-api, google-drive

Mi problema es que necesito poder detectar la creación de un nuevo archivo (archivo de video) para poder descargarlo y no tener que descargar la lista completa o todos los archivos presentes en el directorio. Me explico: estoy creando un script PHP el cual pueda descargar solo archivos nuevos, estos archivos son subidos automáticamente por ZOOM a una cuenta de administrador en Google Drive, pero ahora necesito poder trabajarlos con mi script. He estado investigando en la documentación de Google drive Api Rest, pero para PHP existe muy poca documentación y la información que [encontré](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/folder) de como modificar carpetas o directorios de Google Drive es limitado, solo permiten obtener algunos metadatos, crear una carpeta nueva o un fichero nuevo.

Actualmente no poseo código como tal, solo lo poco que otorga el [ejemplo](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/php) de inicio de la api desde la web oficial.

Yo pensaba en crear un método de filtro guardando la lista anterior en una variable estática y luego filtrar la nueva con la vieja para obtener una nueva lista, pero tendría un problema si el Script se detuviese y comenzara de nuevo a ejecutarse y se perdiese los datos estáticos de la variable (eso creo, aunque soy novato en PHP) y no puedo guardar esta lista locamente en el equipo, porque mi script no debe dejar rastro de datos.

Espero su pronta ayuda y disculpen mi ignorancia soy nuevo en PHP y de como trabajan las Api de Google en este lenguaje. Gracias.

Comment: La solución a esto se puede hacer a través de un webhook que te mande una notificación cada que un archivo es subido y luego, se revisa si el mimeType del archivo es un video y si es así, se descarga.

Comment: Gracias amigo por su apoyo.

Comment: La documentación que tenés que seguir es esta https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/push

Comment: gracias y procederé ha implementarlo en mi script.